# Error overloading procedure in Delphi

Tags: delphi, overriding, overloading

For some reason I am now getting this error '[DCC Error] MyFile.pas(52): E2137 Method 'Assign' not found in base class'.  Here is a snipit of my Assign procedures that worked fine until I added one more, the last Assign.

```
procedure Assign(MyClass: TMyClass); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: ThisService.MyClass); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: ThatService.MyClass); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: TXMLMyClass); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: pbStruct1Messages.TMyRecord); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: pbStruct2Messages.TMyRecord); overload; override;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `override`, you're saying that you're overriding the virtual method with the same signature inherited from a parent class. If the parent class doesn't have a virtual method with that signature, then the compiler will rightly complain that it can't find it.

Check the ancestor classes to confirm that the method really exists. If it doesn't exist, then don't mark the one in the descendant class with `override`.

Comment: Rob, Thanks for making me dive further.  I discovered the parent class didn't have the function for my 'pbStruct2Messages.TMyRecord' Assign to override.

Comment: I need to add that if the parent class has the corresponging virtual method but in the 'private' section, the child class won't find it. It has to be in 'protected'.

Answer (score -3):

```
procedure Assign(MyClass: pbStruct1Messages.TMyClass); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: pbStruct2Messages.TMyClass); overload; override;
```

I think thihs is error, you make two equals parameter TMyClass. Use somelike

```
procedure Assign(MyClass: pbStruct1Messages); overload; override;
procedure Assign(MyClass: pbStruct2Messages); overload; override;
```

Comment: pbStruct1Messages is a namespace or a .pas file - its not a type. You can not do this

Comment: Yes, it's my bad. But i think what TMyClass - it's error

Comment: No, `TMyClass` in both those units are treated as different classes. That's the reason why the namespace is there.

Comment: My fault, when making the names generic, the last 2 assigns are NOT TMyClass, they are in fact records so I renamed above accordingly.  I can see why that would've been an issue, my apologies.